# Output data with grep after symbol match

Tags: grep, html-parsing, cut

I have the following script:

```
grep "John" uk-500.html | cut -d "<" -f2 | grep -v "St"
```

Which searches for John in file uk-500.html, and prints everything before second "<".
I get following result:

```
TD ALIGN="LEFT">Berry, John M Esq
TD ALIGN="LEFT">Cain, John M Esq
TD ALIGN="LEFT">Cavuto, John A
TD ALIGN="LEFT">Cheek, John D Esq
TD ALIGN="LEFT">Elliott, John W Esq
TD ALIGN="LEFT">Gallagher, John J Esq
TD ALIGN="LEFT">Graham, John A Esq
TD ALIGN="LEFT">Hancock, John J Esq
TD ALIGN="LEFT">Howard Johnson
TD ALIGN="LEFT">John Noda A Law Ofc Lawrence E
TD ALIGN="LEFT">Johnson, Matthew E Esq
```

Question is, which attributes should I use to make it structured in this way: "Surname, Name" and no html tags before?

Comment: Please paste your code & results directly into the question, rather than posting to an outside service like pastebin.  The external code can go away at any time, and there is no version control over it like with SO questions.  Therefore, future readers will probably not be able to see the external code and thus this question will be useless or not make much sense. **StackOverflow is as much about future reference for others as it is about you getting your question answered today.**

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do this.  one way would be to add one more pipe to your sequence:

```
grep "John" uk-500.html | cut -d "<" -f2 | grep -v "St" | sed 's/^.*>//'
```

this call to sed searches your output and removes everything from each line matching the regular expression pattern `^.*>`.  this effectively removes the content of the original html tag from the beginning of each line.

this may not be the most ideal way to do it, but it definitely does the job with your example data.